# Compare between two datatables and merge into new datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Suppose i have two data table contain same column name, But record may or may not be the same. My question is how to compare between two data table and marge into new one.
example:

**datatable 1**

```
Name     value
A           1
B           2
C           3   
D           4
```

**datatable 2**

```
Name    value
A        9
B        2
D        1
```

**New datatable(Compare based on datatable 1)**

```
Name    value(From1)   value(From2)
A             1            9
B             2            2
C             3 
D             4            1
```

If a record present in `datatable1` is not present in `datatable2` then add blank. Here the datatable generate from XML. I am using vb.net 2008 express.

Answer (score 3):

Create a primary key on the `Name` column. Then make sure the `value` columns have different names (like `value1` and `value2`). Then simply use [`Merge()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

**Example:**

```
Dim dt1 = New DataTable()
dt1.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt1.Columns.Add("value1", GetType(Integer))
dt1.Rows.Add({"A", 1})
dt1.Rows.Add({"B", 2})
dt1.Rows.Add({"C", 3})
dt1.Rows.Add({"D", 4})
dt1.PrimaryKey = {dt1.Columns("Name")}

Dim dt2 = New DataTable()
dt2.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
dt2.Columns.Add("value2", GetType(Integer))
dt2.Rows.Add({"A", 9})
dt2.Rows.Add({"B", 2})
dt2.Rows.Add({"D", 1})
dt2.PrimaryKey = {dt2.Columns("Name")}

dt1.Merge(dt2)
```

`dt1` now looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I Think below code will help you

```
    'dtTable1 - First Table
    'dtTable2 - Secound Table
    'dtNewData - Result Table

    Dim dtNewData As New DataTable
    dtNewData = dtTable1.Copy()
    dtNewData.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtNewData.Columns("Name")}
    dtNewData.Columns.Add("Value2")
    For Each dr As DataRow In dtTable2.Rows
        If dtNewData.Rows.Contains(dr("Name")) = False Then
            Dim dr1 As DataRow = dtNewData.NewRow
            dr1("Name") = dr("Name")
            dr1("Value2") = dr("Value")
            dtNewData.Rows.Add(dr1)
        Else
            dtNewData.Rows.Find(dr("Name"))("Value2") = dr("Value")
        End If
    Next
```